# How to edit Sql query in aspx.file using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Below is my query which i want to edit in aspx file

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>
     "InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Sales] ([ReceiptID], [EmployeeID], [Discount], [Date])
      VALUES (@ReceiptID, @EmployeeID, @Discount, @Date)">
```

I want to replace the @EmployeeID with  a global variable value.
How can i do that. This global variable is saved in a class which I can access by `global_var_session.GID`.

Comment: Are you saying that the name of your field is not actually [EmployeeID] but is actually the value stored in global_var_session.GID?

Comment: sorry see the edited question i want to replace that @employeeid with a global value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InsertParameters:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Sales] ([ReceiptID], [EmployeeID], [Discount], [Date])
 VALUES (@ReceiptID, @Gid, @Discount, @Date)">

    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gid" Type="String" />
        ...define other parameters...
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And in code-behind use

```
SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Gid"].DefaultValue = global_var_session.GID;
...set other parameter values...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the InsertCommand from the aspx and move it to the cs.
Then in the .cs under the appropriate event handler:

```
SqlDatasource2.InsertCommand= "your query string with the reference to your Global Variable"
```